Java/terminal issues when getting and printing out utf-8 encoded strings
I've wanted to make an utf 8 supported chatroom, but it didn't work only for some specific utf 8 characters, so after spending a week in pure frustration, i narrowed it down to something being wrong with my user input handling, i asked chatgpt too and read countless forums but i couldn't figure it out.
I'm on Windows, I use vscode, updated version, the terminal there uses utf8 encoding i checked with chcp - returns 65001, same goes for cmd, so i don't think its a problem with the terminal, i tried brute forcing java System.out to be in utf-8 didn't fix it
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
I don't have a problem when i have preset a String containing utf8 encoded characters and print that out
for example:
String random = "háló";
System.out.println(random);


returns: háló`

I've tried Scanner, BufferedReader, InputStreamReader, converting to bytes
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            );
            System.out.println("Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):");
            String userInput = reader.readLine();
            
            // Print the user input to verify
            System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
            byte[] bytes = userInput.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


returns:
Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):
háló
You entered: hl
[104, 0, 108, 0]

note: im a beginner java dev, coming from python
EDIT:
New findings/ mentioning previously left out things:
so i could run a python chatroom before that was able to use utf 8 encoded characters and print them out correctly, as I mentioned in java I was able to print them out too if i preset them to a variable, but not when i return them from user input
I downloaded intellij and tried out more terminals, and found out it worked correctly in intellij and in bash (with windows subsystem for linux):
Intellij:
Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):
háló
You entered: háló
[104, -61, -95, 108, -61, -77]

bash:
root@DESKTOP:/mnt/x/javaProjects/UTF 8 SUFFERING# java Main
Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):
háló
You entered: háló
[104, -61, -95, 108, -61, -77]
root@DESKTOP:/mnt/x/javaProjects/UTF 8 SUFFERING# java -version
openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+9-Ubuntu-122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+9-Ubuntu-122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

it is interesting that it prints out a different byte array.
Now i tried cmd, powershell, git bash, vscode terminal and those don't work.
I have also tried different fonts as suggested by SedJ601
and it was interesting because by default i used consolas on cmd which supports utf8 characters (so it recognised characters like "á" and displayed them correctly, but when java returned it from user input it didn't work):
Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):
háló
You entered: h l
[104, 0, 108, 0]

but when i tried different font for example SimSun-ExtB I got different byte arrays and results:
Enter some text (UTF-8 characters supported):
háló
You entered: h�l�
[104, -17, -65, -67, 108, -17, -65, -67]

so there is something wrong with how java and my terminal interacts
I have recent version of java
X:\javaProjects\UTF 8 SUFFERING>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.11+9 (build 17.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.11+9 (build 17.0.11+9, mixed mode, sharing)

i tried setting enviorment variables which didn't fix anything:
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

and java is set to utf 8, so im even more confused:
X:\javaProjects\UTF 8 SUFFERING>java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Property settings:
    file.encoding = UTF-8

maybe java and my terminals use a different lookup table for special characters, or i have no idea. I even changed the system locale to my country, that didn't help either i'm clueless any help would be appreciated!

It looks like your input is coming from the keyboard. I don't think that's your issue. Printing to the Console/Command Prompt is more likely your issue, IMO. Make sure your console is using a font that is UTF8 compatible.  To test things. I would simple try to print a string with UTF8 characters. They will help you identify if the issue is from the input or output. System.out.println("He said \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645 to me.");

This may help. It's JavaFX, but my guess is that your issue is similar.

Worthwhile checking in system properties whether UTF-8 language support is enabled

UTF-8 characters supported Incidentally, there's no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". UTF-8 is an *encoding scheme". 'Exotic' characters can be encoded in many different ways. Depending on how things are set to encode the input, there could be zero Unicode input coming in at all

Your code is otherwise fine though your output would be probably better as hex

Thanks SedJ601, that seems to be the issue for some reason it works only in intellij terminal, but still dont know why in other place it doesn't work

The console app running your Java app must be set to use UTF-8 character encoding. As a Java programmer, you have no control over that. Despite this being 2024, way too many console/terminal apps default to some legacy character encoding rather than the obvious choice of UTF-8.
